# Remove all HTML tags and attributes from a string

Tags: php, html, mysql, joomla

I am retrieving data from the table in a MySQL database which was created by the Joomla framework. I want to encode that data in JSON format. After retrieving the data there are many unnecessary tags and style properties. I tried `html_entity_decode`, `strip_tags` and many more built in functions but they didn't work for me. Can anyone tell me how to remove all those tags and styles attributes from the retrieved data and get plain text only.

Comment: Post some of the data you are trying to encode. Why did strip_tags not work? Was the data encoded(htmlentities)?

Comment: Using `strip_tags` would be the right way to do this. Could you elaborate on how they are not working? What happens when you use them?

Comment: What you are asking is confusing because you start by saying you want to retrieve data ... is that data encoded in JSON already? If so why don't you strip the tags prior to saving?  Joomla also has built in functions for that.  But if you don't post: data you are retrieving, what you want to get, and what you are getting no one can really help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove HTML tags using the `strip_tags` function like this:

```
echo strip_tags("Hello <b>world!</b>");
```

It will remove all HTML tags from the string.

Comment: I have used many functions brother... But couldn't get the plain needed text only...

Comment: User said that he strip_tags() is not working for him

Comment: @Arpita: he only added that after I posted my answer

Comment: using echo and showing on browser easily worked. But I am trying to encode them using json_encode function and it returns false.. I thought it was because of html tags and style attributes...Is there any other way to encode those data...??

Comment: @ShreeKrishna No, it is not because of those functions. You need to ad this information and the code you use for the JSON encoding to your original question. As it is stated right now, the two answers you got accurately solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

Comment: User said that he strip_tags() is not working for him

Comment: @Arpita That was edited after both answers were posted (probably as a response to them). Who ever is downvoting should be avare of that.

Comment: Maybe, you could remove this answer

Answer (score 0):

I used [Apache Common lang Liabrary](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) to escape all the html tags like this

```
String escapedValue= org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(unescapedValue);
```

And used Html.fromHtml() to set it to TextView.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(escapedValue));
```